# Как в IntelliJ IDEA сделать значок для jar файла?

Tags: java, jar, icon

Чтобы он заменял чашку кофе :)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что, вопрос не соответствует теме форума.

Comment: @a_gura но при этом он [соответствует теме enSO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590885/how-to-change-executable-jar-file-icon) :)

Answer (score 3):

У самого `jar` - никак, у него иконка определяется ассоциацией файла в windows.

Можно обернуть `jar` в `exe` с помощью [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/) - и поставить иконку на ваш вкус.